# Combinatorics contest math problem

Tags: combinatorics, induction, contest-math

The problem is:

> We have $n(n+1)/2$ stones in $k$ piles. In each move we take one stone from each pile and form a new pile with these stones (if a pile has only one stone, after that stone is removed the pile vanishes). Show that regardless of the initial configuration, we always end up with n piles, having $1, 2, 3, \dots, n$ stones each.

My "Solution":
I started by noticing that if we denote $f(x) = y$ our transformation from one configuration of stones to the other than $f(x) = x$ has only one solution $x = 1, 2, 3, \dots, n$. Then, because for each number of stones (not necessary of the form $n(n+1)/2$) the number of possible configurations is finite we will always end up in a cycle that will repeat itself forever. I noticed from the Python script i wrote that for each initial number of stones regardless of the initial configuration we always end up in the same cycle and i wanted to prove it by induction thus completing the proof, with the induction base: for $p = 1$  stones we only have one cycle $1\to 1 \to 1\to \dots$ and the induction step: if $p > 1$ has more then one different cycle then p-1 has more then one different cycle too. If we don’t have a pile with only one stone for any combination in our cycle then we can just remove a stone from the pile with the maximum amount of stones for every configuration of the cycle thus giving us a cycle for $p-1$ stones. I’m stuck on the case when we have a pile with only one stone in a configuration of the cycle.

Is there a simpler solution? Is there some core idea that i didn’t notice? can my proof be completed?
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is known as *[Bulgarian solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_solitaire)*. A beautiful proof that  starting with $n(n+1)/2$ stones the procedure will converge into piles of size $1, 2,\dots , n$ is given as Theorem 1 in [The Bulgarian solitaire and the mathematics around it](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00885v1.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! That’s beautiful!

Comment: your second link seems to have a typo

Comment: @SayanDutta Thanks for pointing out. Now it works!

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's a great argument.